# JavaScript Form Validation Query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've just wrote some validation code so as to check if either of my `radio` buttons from my web form have been selected before they are submitted.  I've just starting learning `php` as I want to be able to store the `value` of each `radio` button in a `.csv` file.

Because I have my `action` attribute set to trigger a `php` script, I get my `alert` box, but as soon as I click `OK` after pressing `submit` the browser goes straight to the `php` script (inevitably).

Is there a way I can return to my initial `index.html` after the `alert` message?

I have not actually written any `php` as yet, so would this go in the `php` script or the `javascript`?

Heres my code so far:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function() {

    var radio = $("input[type=radio][name=emotion]")[0].checked;
    var radio2 = $("input[type=radio][name=emotion]")[1].checked;
    var radio3 = $("input[type=radio][name=emotion]")[2].checked;

    if(!radio && !radio2 && !radio3) {
        alert("You must select at least one word!");
    }
    else {
        alert("Please rate the next item!")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jquery you should use [.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) function to validate a form.
Then to avoid to submit the form you can use the function [event.preventDefault()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)
And if you want to go to the index you can use `window.location = "yourURL"`

Comment: Thanks - so instead of `$("#submit").on("click"....` I change it to `$("#submit").submit(function(event)....` and place `event.preventDefault();` within my `if` statement?

Comment: Cool - I'll have a play with the code as there seems to be a lot of different ways around this problem :-)

Comment: So what is the difference between a regular `onclick` function and a `submit` function?  Do you mean the latter actually does the validation for you, or does it mean that using `submit` lets you access more properties and methods, etc. like `event.preventDefault`?  Sorry for all the questions!

Comment: click function just works when you click the button, but there are different ways to submit a form ( click to another button, keyboard, etc). So .submit() is the proper way to handler the form.

The event.preventDefault can be used always to prevent the default behaviour of a handler. ( prevent the contextual menu to pop up, change the behaviour of F1 key, etc )

Answer (score 1):

You must use form.onsubmit().
For example, if your form's name is myForm:

```
document.forms['myForm'].onsubmit = function()
{
    if (this.elements['emotion'].value)
    {
        alert("Please rate the next item!");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("You must enter at least one word!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

And after alert "Please rate the next item!" form will be send.

Comment: Thanks - is `onSubmit` a Javascript or jquery function?

Comment: It's javascript handler of form. In jquery - $(form).submit(function() {});

Comment: Thanks again - its all coming together a little now after all the useful responses I've had so far.  I wish I could tick all the questions as correct!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use jquery `$.post()` , an easy solution is just to post your php page without leaving index page.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$.post( "yourpage.php" );
```

Comment: I see - so instead of putting the script to launch within the `action` attribute of the `form` tag/element, I can just pop that line of code anywhere in my Javascript whenever I want a `php`script to be triggered?

Comment: @user1574598 exactly whenever you want to post your php page ( it is like you open this page in background ) , you can use this simple code , ofcourse this is simplest , you can check response from php ( the returned data ) as well.

Comment: Thanks - thats useful information as I thought I was bound to the `form` tag in terms of triggering `php`scripts :-)

Comment: no ofcourse not , also you can post data to that php page check everything here :http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ , glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the input type of the submit button as submit? Set this to button, so the action doesn't take place and only jQuery is executed.

But then you have to submit the form by jQuery when validation was successful:

```
document.myFormId.submit();
```